# How to find 2 vertex-disjoint paths in a graph with both paths having same source but different destination?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, dijkstra

Let's consider this graph:

[image]

Let's say
I want first path with source as A, destination as H and
I want second path with source as A, destination as D.

I am not able to apply suurballe algorithm as it works for paths with same source and same destination only.
Expected O/p is first path => A-E-F-G-H, second path => A-B-C-D. These two are vertex disjoint paths.
How to calculate 2 vertex disjoint paths in this situation?

Comment: to clarify: the requirement is that the algorithm finds vertex disjoint paths to the two target vertices if such paths exist, but they are not required to be the shortest path to the respective target vertices?

Comment: I think you could add an additional vertex X and connect D and H to X Then use  suurballe and remove X from the two result paths. As X is only reachable via D and H, those must be the last points before X in the two paths.

Comment: @Robin - please turn that comment into an answer so it can be upvoted & (maybe) accepted. It's a great idea that solves the question easily.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Robin, please change your comment to answer, I shall accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach that works quite well for many problems is to think about how to transform it into one you can solve.

In this case: You already know the [Suurballe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suurballe%27s_algorithm) algorithm that can solve the problem of vertex disjoint paths if the target vertex of both is the same.
So to solve your problem, you can just add a vertex *X* to your graph and connect *D* and *H* to it. Then execute Suurballe's algorithm with start *A* and target *X* and remove *X* from the end of the returned paths. As the only way to reach *X* is via *D* and *H*, those must be the last ones in the path before *X*.